# C++ "cannot add two pointers", adding a hardcoded string to a CString

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I get this error quite often when I try to do something like this

```
CString filePath = theApp->GetSystemPath() + "test.bmp";
```

The compiler tells me

```
error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

But if I change it to this below it works fine?

```
CString filePath = theApp->GetSystemPath();
filePath += "test.bmp";
```

The function `GetSystemPath` returns a LPCTSTR if that has anything to do with it

Comment: what happends if you change it to CString(theApp->GetSystemPath()) + CString("test.bmp"); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the types of objects that you are dealing with.

```
CString filePath = theApp->GetSystemPath() + "test.bmp";
```

The line above is attempting to add the type of GetSystemPath() with "test.bmp" or an LPCTSTR + char[];  The compiler does not know how to do this because their is no + operator for these two types.

The reason this works:

```
filePath += "test.bmp";
```

Is because you are doing CString + char[] (char*);  The CString class has the + operator overloaded to support adding CString + char*.  Or alternatively which is constructing  a CString from a char* prior to applying the addition operator on two CString objects.  LPCTSTR does not have this operator overloaded or the proper constructors defined.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can't add two pointers. The reason `filePath += "test.bmp";` works is that the left hand side is a CString not a pointer. This would also work

```
CString(theApp->GetSystemPath()) + "test.bmp";
```

and so would this

```
theApp->GetSystemPath() + CString("test.bmp");
```

The rules of C++ prevent you overloading operators unless at least one of the argument is of class type. So it's not possible for anyone to overload operator+ for pointers only.

Answer (score 2):

When doing this:

```
CString filePath = theApp->GetSystemPath() + "test.bmp";
```

You are trying to *sum two pointers* of type `const char*`. As the compiler is telling you, there is no overload of `operator +` that accepts two pointers of type `const char*`s as its input (after all, what you want is not to sum the pointers, but to concatenate the zero-terminated strings pointed to by those pointers).

On the other hand, there is an overload of `operator +=` (as well as of `operator +`) that takes a `CString` and a `const char*`, which is why the second example compiles. For the same reason, this would also work:

```
CString filePath = theApp->GetSystemPath() + CString("test.bmp");
```

As well as this:

```
CString filePath = CString(theApp->GetSystemPath()) + "test.bmp";
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may not be aware that the programmer is intending to concatenate two strings. it merely sees that a `char const *` is being added with another using the `+` operator.

I'd try something like this:

```
CString filePath = CString( theApp->GetSystemPath() ) + CString( "test.bmp" );
```